# Why is there a gap between the header and the main div?

Tags: html, css, menu, header, nav

There is a gap between the `header` and the `main` that is the same color as the background color I set for the `body` tag (black). I've tried making `overflow: hidden` and `margin: 0` but that did not work either.

What is causing this gap?

(`.menu` does not show if the `menu` button has not been clicked - so `display: none`)

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Gotham;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

main {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  height: 3.4rem;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  overflow-x: none;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.top {
  background-color: var(--purple);
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.top-container {
    margin: 2rem 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-container">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <img src="img/user.png" alt="">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-bars fa-xl"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<nav class="menu">
  <div class="menu-container">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
</nav>
<main>
  <section class="top">
    <div class="top-container">
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

How do I get rid of the gap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that all I needed to do was make the `top-container` `margin-top: 0`. The `margin` for the top and bottom before was at `2rem`.

So it looked like:

```
.top-container {
    margin: 0rem 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

So to add space between the top of the container and the content, you need to add `margin` to the actual content not the `container`.

Answer (score 0):

I added background-color to header and main to see if there is a gap. There's no gap man? Could you please show where the gap is ?

```css
body {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Gotham;
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

main {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:red;
}

header {
    height: 3.4rem;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:green;
}

.menu {
    display: none;
    overflow-x: none;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.top {
    background-color: var(--purple);
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="header-container">
            <div class="left">
                <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <img src="img/user.png" alt="">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-bars fa-xl"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <nav class="menu">
        <div class="menu-container">
            <-- content -->
        </div>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <section class="top">
            <div class="top-container">
               <-- content -->
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
```

Comment: The gap was added by adding `margin` to `.top-container`. I didn't not add that in the question.